# algorithm efficiency

Tags: summation

```
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for (int j=i;j<=n;j++){
        do_something
    }
}
```

I need to calculate how many times the "do something" step happens.

I started like so:

$\sum _{i=1}^n\:\sum _{j=i}^n\:1$

I got stuck here trying to open the inner sum.
I know that the algorithm is O(n^2) but I find it hard to prove it.

Comment: $\sum_{j=i}^n 1=n-i+1$ so the sum is $n^2-\sum_i i + n$.

Comment: @Student can you explain how you got the last sum? $\sum _{i=1}^n\:\sum _{j=i}^n\:1 = \sum _{i=1}^n\:(n-i+1)$

Comment: It is from breaking up the summand and substituting with multiplication by $n$ where the same expression is repeated $n$ times: $\sum_{i=1}^n (n-i+1) = \sum_i n - \sum_i i + \sum_i 1 = n^2 -\sum_i i + n$.

Comment: @Student thanks! can you write an answer to the post so I can select it as an answer?

Comment: @Andrei’s answer is good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sum _{i=1}^n\:\sum _{j=i}^n\:1&=\sum_{i=1}^n(n-i+1)\\&=n\sum_{i=1}^n1-\sum_{i=1}^ni+\sum_{i=1}^n1\\&=n^2-\frac{n(n+1)}2+n\\&=\frac{n^2}2+\frac {n}2\end{align}$$

Comment: Did you mean $\sum_i i = n (n+1)/2$?

Comment: Yes. I'll fix it. Thanks

Comment: @Andrei thank you!